# Setting terminal to show latest output in another color

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to set the mac terminal to output its lastest output in a different color?

I am tired of wasting time looking for the last command when the terminal gets filled.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could arrange for your [prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt) to be in a different color.  You could also split the pane; the bottom will scroll with the output while the top stays wherever it was.